# Can I require developers to include method docstrings before committing their code on gitlab?

Tags: python, gitlab, documentation

We're running a project with some developers and I would like to impose the condition that a developer cannot commit / push code to a branch before including docstrings in every method / function. Is this possible to implement with gitlab or in general?

Comment: I foresee a lot of `'''This is a docstring.'''` in your future.

Comment: @JohnGordon perhaps, but the team is small enough that we can weed out the lazy people who do this

Comment: Mabybe you can do this from each local machine of developers by using git pre-commit hook. I don't have full solution but you can get a way from this link http://wadmiraal.net/lore/2014/07/14/how-git-hooks-made-me-a-better-and-more-lovable-developer/